# C# WebService using WebAPI and Entity for XML tutorial?

Tags: c#, web-services, entity-framework-6, webapi

in the last two days I am trying to locate such a tutorial.

There have been years since I wrote my last webservice (I am mostly an SQL coder) and it was an amsx one which I read that are now considered non-secured and there is trouble getting them working with XMLs (<,> character issues).

I have a task to build a webservice using C# and Entity Framework (with a brutal deadline). It should receive ("consume" is the correct word?) XMLs, parse them and do database operations.
I read that WebAPI is the most suitable for this.

I would greatly appreciate if you can link me to a tutorial or give me some first steps

Thank you

Comment: In case you haven't recent experience with such tasks and the brutal deadline, I suggest you build a monolithic application (instead of microservices) with the help of WebAPI, EF Core, and RDBMS, which probably give you maximal productivity and comfort. As a quick introduction, I suggest reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/ from Microsoft (skip irrelevant parts).

Comment: Thank you but the task is for a webservice that will accept OTA (Open Travel Alliance) XML requests